# @Sort is not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to understand how sorting works in Hibernate with a small example. I have created below entities:

`User.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_ID")
    @Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = TicketComparator.class)
    private SortedSet<Ticket> tickets = new TreeSet<Ticket>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, Ticket...tickets) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tickets.addAll(Arrays.asList(tickets));
    }
}
```

`Ticket.java`

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comparator class:

```
public class TicketComparator implements Comparator<Ticket> {
    public int compare(Ticket t1, Ticket t2) {
        return t1.getName().compareTo(t2.getName());
    }
}
```

Program to test this:

```
    private static void saveUsers() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = new User("User", new Ticket("abc"), new Ticket("xyz"));
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

private static void showUsers() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();

        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.getName() + " -- > " + user.getTickets());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

When I run this program I am getting exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.tutorials.Ticket cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tutorials.hibernate7.five.sorted.User.<init>(User.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.tutorials.hibernate7.five.sorted.AppTest.saveUsers(AppTest.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.tutorials.hibernate7.five.sorted.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:11)
```

If I have already provided `comparator` attribute then why hibernate is not picking my comparator class but throwing an exception. Please let me know if I am missing anything in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User user = new User("User", new Ticket("abc"), new Ticket("xyz"));
```

The above is pure Java code, that has nothing to do with Hibernate. You are creating an instance of the User class (not Hibernate), and you are populating it with tickets (not Hibernate). The TreeSet is initialized by

```
private SortedSet<Ticket> tickets = new TreeSet<Ticket>();
```

So, you're creating the set without providing a comparator. The set is thus sorted using the natural ordering of the Ticket class. But Ticket doesn't implement `Comparable`, hence the exception.

If you ask Hibernate to get a user from the database, then Hibernate will create an instance of User, will replace your TreeSet with its own collection, using the comparator provided in the annotation, and your tickets will be sorted properly.